# How to know the Activities history in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a couple of activities

`MainActivity` and `SecondActivity`

The `MainActivity` is the fist activity to run and then I click on a button to go the the `SecondActivity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
this.startActivity(i);
```

in the `SecondActivity` I just press back button to go back to the `MainActivity`

I want to execute code in the OnResume function when I'm coming back from the SecondActivity

```
   @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        //code to be executed


    }
```

So how to know that I'm coming back from the `SecondActivity` ?

Comment: by reading the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: The solution might differ according to your situation. Why do you need to know if you came back from SecondActivity? There are two possible solitions. Either use a bundle and putExtra... Or use startActivityForResult when starting SecondActivity then use onActivityResult in your MainActivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a requestCode with `startActivityForResult`. requestCode is an integer that will let you know which activity is returned later. You can create an integer like this to reference in multiple places

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_SECOND_ACTIVITY = 1;
```

Then start your activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_SECOND_ACTIVITY);
```

When you are done with your second activity, you can send back any data you need, or set a custom resultCode for certain actions

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("myData", myVariable);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

To do something after `SecondActivity` finished, you need to override `onActivityResult` in your first activity.

NOTE: If you don't call `setResult` before finishing the second activity, `onActivityResult` will return with the resultCode `RESULT_CANCELLED`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SECOND_ACTIVITY) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "A result code specified by the second activity. This is either RESULT_OK if the operation was successful or RESULT_CANCELED if the user backed out or the operation failed for some reason." You can also specify your own custom result code when you finish the second activity